# Get Log Analytics Workspace key from Bicep

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-log-analytics, azure-bicep

In a bicep file for an App Service, I want to grab the id and key from an existing Log Analytic Workbench, created in another repo/bicep file.

I see this is possible in [Terraform](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/log_analytics_workspace#primary_shared_key), but cannot find any docs on how to achieve this with Bicep, which seems a bit odd.

What I thought should be possible would be something like this;

```
// Refer to existing Log Analytics Workbench
resource logAnalyticsWorkspace 'Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces@2022-10-01' existing = {
  name: logAnalyticsWorkspaceName
}
```

and then doing something like;

```
logAnalyticsWorkspace.properties.keys.primary_shared_key
```

Any tips?

Comment: Maybe listKeys will work, something like logAnalyticsWorkspace.listKeys().keys[0].value .  Typically that is how you get keys like that, I have used for storage account but not log analytics.  More info here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-resource#list

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you would need to use the [listKeys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-resource#list) function:

```bicep
// Get a reference to the existing log analytics workspace
resource logAnalyticWorkspace 'Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces@2021-06-01' existing = {
  name: logAnalyticWorkspaceName
}

var primaryKey = logAnalyticWorkspace.listKeys().primarySharedKey
```

Comment: Will this work safely if your workspace is in a module? I'm trying to get the output of the key from the module and this is not advised as outputs are not safe.

Comment: I now get a warning when using `listKeys(...)` saying  I should use `a resource reference` instead.